# RabbitMQ command doesn't exist?

Tags: macos, rabbitmq

**OS: Mac OSX 10.9**

I have `rabbitmq` installed via home brew and when I go to `/usr/local/sbin` and run `rabbitmq-server` it states that: `rabbitmq-server: command not found` even as sudo it states the same error.

How do I get rabbitmq to start if it's not a command? I have also tried `chmod +x rabbitmq-server` in that directory to get it be an executable, same issue.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-homebrew.html):

> The RabbitMQ server scripts are installed into /usr/local/sbin. This is not automatically added to your path, so you may wish to add
>   PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin to your .bash_profile or .profile. The server can then be started with rabbitmq-server.
>
> All scripts run under your own user account. Sudo is not required.

You should be able to run `/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-server` or add it to your path to run it anywhere.

---

Your command failed because, by default, `.` is not on your `$PATH`. You went to the right directory (`/usr/local/sbin`) and *wanted* to run the `rabbitmq-server` that *existed* and *had exec permissions*, but by typing `rabbitmq-server` as a command Unix only searches for that command on your `$PATH` directories - which didn't include `/usr/local/sbin`.

What you *wanted* to do can be achieved by typing `./rabbitmq-server` - say, *execute the `rabbitmq-server` program that is in the current directory*. That's analogous to running `/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-server` from everywhere - `.` represents your current directory, so it's the same as `/usr/local/sbin` in that context.

Comment: Strangely, I don't see to have a `/usr/local/sbin` folder in the first place.

Comment: Strange, I only see the directory after installing rabbitmq on OSX using homebrew. What is your OS?

Answer (score 63):

My OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

My RabbitMQ was installed using:

```
brew install rabbitmq
```

And it was installed into `/usr/local/Cellar`, just in case if someone has same situation with me, you would need to do similarly:

In terminal:

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/
```

to check which version you have installed, and then add to `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/<version>/sbin:$PATH
```

Comment: In case you're using the Fish shell, add `set PATH $PATH /usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.7.16/sbin` (with the appropriate version number) to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`.

Answer (score 40):

**On mac**  by this command you can start,restart or stop rabbitmq

```
brew services start rabbitmq
brew services stop  rabbitmq
brew services restart rabbitmq
```

Comment: FYI to __stop__ `brew services stop rabbitmq`

Answer (score 35):

As rabbitmq-server resides in `/usr/local/sbin`, running this command will enable starting server from anywhere:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Comment: I'm using Sierra 10.12.3 ... your command did not work for me. However, this command worked when I put it inside my `.zshrc` file:

`PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin`

Comment: Don't forget to restart your terminal after this... (on mac)

Answer (score 5):

I installed using home brew and I did the following:

`brew install rabbitmq.`

encountered issues cause the installation happened under bin and not /usr/local/sbin

So I did the following:

`` 1. chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/sbin
2. chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/share
3. brew install rabbitmq
4. /usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-server ``

And then the server runs and you can login to the management console :

`http://localhost:15672/
userame: guest
password: guest`

Answer (score 3):

Start the service like this:

```
brew services start rabbitmq
```

Or if you don't need to start it as service:

```
/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-server
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case the paths `/usr/local/sbin/` nor `/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/` etc., did not work as Homebrew was putting these all together in a different location.

I opened `Finder` in my Mac and searched for `rabbitmq-server` in the search textbox on top right corner of the `Finder` window.

`rabbitmq-server` was located under the path below:

`/Users/${USER}/homebrew/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.7.15/sbin`

So in my `~/.bash_profile` , I updated the `PATH` as below:

`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/${USER}/homebrew/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.7.15/sbin`

After `source ~/.bash_profile`

```
~ $ rabbitmq-server

  ##  ##
  ##  ##      RabbitMQ 3.7.15. Copyright (C) 2007-2019 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##########  Licensed under the MPL.  See https://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ######  ##
  ##########  Logs: /Users/santoshsindham/homebrew/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
                    /Users/santoshsindham/homebrew/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost_upgrade.log

              Starting broker...
 completed with 6 plugins.
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add this in your ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/rabbitmq/sbin
```

Answer (score 2):

I installed using HomeBrew I added this to my bash profile

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I have Mac OS version 10.13.6 installed. Somehow I did not have `sbin` directory present under `/usr/local/`. On carefully looking I found that for me the `rabbitmq-server` binary was present here `/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.7.9/sbin/rabbitmq-server`.

Answer (score 1):

i have read a wonderful article to fix that

simply open your `bash_profile` or `.profile`.

```
sudo nano ./bash_profile
```

in the begin of the file add `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin`, close and save, then write `source ~/.bash_profile` and lastly restart your terminal.

problem fix it!

http://www.andrewcranston.me/en/engineering/rabbitmq-and-path-variable/